# Master Page can only access control using FindControl

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I've got a strange bug in one of my master pages where, in Visual Studio I can access the control normally.

i.e. `Me.lblName.Text = "abc"`.

This compiles fine. However, when it runs, I get the usual null reference error. The only way to set the properties of any of the controls is to use

```
Me.FindControl("lblError").Text = "abc"
```

Seems for some reason, the controls are not being initialised properly. I know I could cheat and load them myself using `init()` etc, but I shouldn't have to. Let me repeat, I'm not trying to access the control from a child page, but the master page itself.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Try to change your Label's ID on the designer to 'lblNam', save, rename back to `lblName', save. On this way the declaration is recreated. Is that control declared in your codebehind class or in the designer.vb?

Comment: Are these controls defined declaratively or created dynamically at runtime ?

Comment: Is the control declared on Master page? And in what page stage (OnLoad, OnInit, OnPreRender...) are you trying to access the control?

Comment: The control is declared in the designer.vb file, and I'm trying to set the text during PageLoad. Renaming the control had no effect, still get an object reference error. This is really puzzling.

Comment: Why don't you upload a small sample of your code online, so we can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

as well as renaming, also try deleting the control and re-add from the toolbox.